# How to Count Days in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm facing difficulty in generating top below table, using following data, please help!

```
text | date
-----------------
aa   | 25-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 26-08-2017
aa   | 27-08-2017
ab   | 25-08-2017
ab   | 25-08-2017
bb   | 25-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
bb   | 26-08-2017
```

I need report like,

```
text | days
-----------
aa   | 3
bb   | 2
ab   | 1
```

Comment: Is it just  count of the rows or you want difference of the dates?

Comment: SQL has a function called `count()`.  If you don't know how to use it, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: I think the challenge he is facing in printing the last line having count only 1

Comment: @Ankit What's your point? There is only one `ab` row in his sample table.

Comment: @venkatesh `select text,count(date) As days from table group by text`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.ct = 1 THEN concat(t.text,  ' count ', t.ct, ' day') 
            ELSE concat(t.text,  ' days count ', t.ct) 
       END
FROM (
   SELECT text, count(date) AS ct
   FROM your_table 
   GROUP BY text
) t
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `count(distinct date)`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you using the fonction timediff()
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php

Comment: 1) The OP is not asking about time difference. 2) You can't recommend specific functions unless you know the SQL engine the OP uses. 3) If you link, link to credible sources, preferably the original documentation. `w3resource` is not a credible source.